# Anatomically Correct Ypotryll

Tags: creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures, anatomically-correct

The Ypotryll is an ungulate with the following appearance: Its head and jaw look like that of a wild boar, and the body is humped like a camel. The legs and feet are bovine, and its tail is long, scaly, and resembles a snake

How could this creature arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ypotryll is a desert-dwelling boar or relative thereof

The humps would be used to store fat, just as in camels. The bovine feet may be retained in the case that they live in rockier areas, where there is no need to spread out their weight

The tail seems strange. One reason for its appearance could be that, if the creature likes to fight, it is used to protect against attacks from behind, with the scales being used for protection and the length allowing it to keep a good guard

Comment: Pangolins evolved scales from mammalian hair. The Ypotryll likely did something similar.